# VueJS and Cloudinary: Why does image break after zoomed in?

Tags: vuejs2, cloudinary

I have a button with click event named `zoomIn` that will replace some image transformation parameters on an img src element with different parameters (basically crops the image at a higher size). The image source is a linked stored image from [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/resizing_and_cropping), an image CDN transformation service.

**The problem is that when you keep clicking the button to zoom in, the image becomes broken.**

Screenshot of broken image:

[image]

Can someone show me how to fix it so that when you click the zoom button after the zoom that it won't break?

I have a codesandbox to show what is happening: https://codesandbox.io/s/cloudinary-zoom-image-542b1?file=/src/App.vue

Here's my VueJS template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container mt-5">
    <button type="button" @click.prevent="zoomIn">Zoom In</button>
    <!-- <button type="button" @click.prevent="zoomout">Zoom Out</button> -->
    <img
      ref="image"
      src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/c_scale,w_400/sample.jpg"
      id="image"
      width="400px"
      alt="flower"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the `zoomIn` method:

```
    zoomIn() {
      // get source
      let img = this.$refs.image;
      console.log("url:", img);

      let src = img.src;

      // split source URL into array of substrings using default image transformation as separator
      let splittedUrlArr = src.split("f_auto,q_auto/c_scale,w_400/");
      console.log("splittedUrlArr", splittedUrlArr);

      // assign new image transformation to splittedUrlArr
      splittedUrlArr[0] += "f_auto,q_auto:best/w_1000/c_crop,w_400";
      console.log(1, splittedUrlArr);

      // return new transformation params to original array
      img.src = splittedUrlArr.join("/");
      console.log(2, img);
    },
```

Thanks, I am novice to JavaScript and VueJS (if there is a better way to write the zoomin logic I'd be happy to know!)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make a component for this? https://codesandbox.io/s/cloudinary-zoom-image-forked-zxpb0?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Wow! yes, so awesome. Let me study and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Lawrence, did you use or need the cloudinary-vue package for that ? I saw it in dependencies list by wasn't sure if you were using it in the actual code.

Comment: no, it looks like codesandbox has added it, though that package seems to do what you need